# Playing sound in flutter from assets using function

Tags: flutter, dart

Please give me a package with thier version and a fuction to play and stop the audio that is passed to the function as string so that sound can be played from asstes.

I have tried every packages but still eroor is shown in every one, and I can't even play sound, once I click to play sound these messages are shown:

```
FlutterSoundPlayer.log (package:flutter_sound/public/flutter_sound_player.dart:500:13)
I/flutter ( 7801): │ #1   MethodChannelFlutterSoundPlayer.channelMethodCallHandler (package:flutter_sound_platform_interface/method_channel_flutter_sound_player.dart:161:19)
I/flutter ( 7801): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter ( 7801): │ ⛔ startPlayer() exception
```